# JSF <f:validateRegex pattern

Tags: java, regex, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I cant understand this:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}" />
```

please someone explain for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}` is a regex for a US phone number, either in the form:

> `555-555-5555` or `(555)555-5555` or `555-5555`

First of all `\d` means digit.

This part `((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?` means `(555)` or `555-`, once or none at all. Broken down its

```
   (       (\(\d{3}\) ?)            |            (\d{3}-)     )   ?

( (3 digits with () ?- once or no)  |-OR  (three digits plus - ) ) ?-once or none
```

This part `\d{3}-` means `555-` (three digits plus -).

This part `\d{4}` means `5555` (four digits).

BTW, the `5`'s are just placeholders for *any digit*.

The `<f:validateRegex pattern` tag and attribute is to validate an input field to match one of the above three patterns.

See more at [Regualar Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)